# Mysql select count per price then per brand per day

Tags: php, mysql

Good day,

This is my first time on this forum and would like to acquire assistance on how do you select in MySQL count per price, per brand per day in which is kind of tricky as the same price may have the same brand. Below is my sample query but not the actual output that I'm expecting, by the way I only have 3 BRAND but multiple price.

```
SELECT orderDate,prepaid_type,vatprice, count(vatprice) as hits

FROM playdough.playdough_transactions

where deliveryStatus='true' AND orderDate LIKE "2015-01%"

AND (refunded='' OR (refunded='Y' AND SUBSTRING(completed_date,1,10) > "2015-11-18"))

GROUP BY vatprice,prepaid_type,orderDate ORDER BY hits,orderDate DESC;
```

Output should be as below:

Ex.

```
  orderDate          prepaid_type        vatprice         hits
  2015-01            IN_HTOCS            100.00           5
                     IN_NSN              150.00           1
                     IN_NSN              100.00           1
                     IN_NEW              20.00            55
                     IN_HTOCS            55.00            123

  2015-02            IN_HTOCS            20.00           21
                     IN_NSN              10.00           11
                     IN_NSN              200.00          2

  2015-03            IN_HTOCS            100.00          5  
                     IN_NSN              10.00           7
                     IN_NSN              11.00           9
```

Grateful for any assistance on this.

Thank you,

Comment: It would be good if you show some input data as well.

Comment: ... and the table structure.

Comment: Please provide a sample table for the queries and the expected outputs...

Comment: Here's the table structure,

Comment: Sorry just a newbie here, I've edited the table for your reference.. please advise if you need further details...